# GoblinXNA - DebugFont.spritefont needs to be added to your content directory - Error (MSVCR90.dll)

Tags: visual-studio, xna

**SOLVED**: This error only occurs in Visual Studio 2010, it doesn't appear in Visual Studio 2008, probably because the Content Pipeline is differently loaded in both. Though the error I've been having with MSVCR90.dll, is the next problem.

---

I have started using the Goblin XNA framework to create an Augmented Reality application. Though it hasn't gone smoothly thus far. The reason I am asking this here on stackoverflow.com is because this seems like a mixture between a Goblin XNA and a Visual Studio issue, so I was hoping I could find some help here.

```
You need to add 'DebugFont.spritefont' file to your content directory before you can display debug information
```

When I Debug CameraCalibration.sln I get the above error, does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

**-- EDIT: This error shows up in the Event Viewer:**

Faulting application name: CameraCalibration.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4e67259c

Faulting module name: MSVCR90.dll, version: 9.0.30729.4974, time stamp: 0x4b7a226f

Exception code: 0xc0000417

Fault offset: 0x0006ccb5

Faulting process id: 0xdc0

Faulting application start time: 0x01cc6d34cfa769a0

Faulting application path: D:\My Documents\user\AR-Demo\GoblinXNAv3.6\tools\CameraCalibration\bin\x86\Release\CameraCalibration.exe

Faulting module path: C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4974_none_50940634bcb759cb\MSVCR90.dll

Report Id: 1296c1c0-d928-11e0-8928-fa12135e51e5

Comment: The error message is pretty descriptive - You need to add 'DebugFont.spritefont' file to your content directory. Is there a spritefont called DebugFont in your content project?

Comment: @MattDavey Yes, it's added as a link in the content pipeline (which it came like out-of-the-box), I've also tried adding it as a file, and putting it in a Fonts folder, both didn't help out. Please check out the EventViewer event log I've added.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the source file throwing this exception here: https://goblinxna.svn.codeplex.com/svn/src/UI/UIRenderer.cs

```
 try
     {
         debugFont = State.Content.Load<SpriteFont>(@"" + Path.Combine(
             State.GetSettingVariable("FontDirectory"), "DebugFont"));
     }
         catch (Exception exp)
     {
     }
```

[...]

```
if (debugFont == null)
    throw new GoblinException("You need to add 'DebugFont.spritefont' file to your " +
                        "content directory before you can display debug information");
```

This does sound like a data problem, after all. Check the file properties for DebugFont.spritefont between both VS installations.